# Overriding for-each xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file, let's say:

```
<parent>
    <notimportant1>
    </notimportant1>.    
    <notimportant2>
    </notimportant2>.   
     ....
    <child>
        <grandchild>.   
         ....
        </grandchild>
        <grandchild>
         ....
        </grandchild>. 
         ....
        <notimportant3>
        </notimportant3>
    </child>
<parent>
```

And there is xsl file:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">.   
      ...
      ...
     <xsl:for-each select="child">.    
         <xsl:for-each select="grandchild">
          ...
         </xsl:for-each>.    
     </xsl:for-each>
      ....
</xsl:template>
```

Now, I have to create new `xsl` file, 
which can only import/include this existing `xsl`.

Is it possible to override this for-each behaviour so that instead of it I could only display some predefined text/link?

I cannot modify existing xsl and I want to use everything else from the template - cannot just define new one with higher priority.

Answer (score 5):

You could redesign your original stylesheet to use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:for-each`. Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  ...   
  ...
  <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
  ....
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="grandchild"/>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="grandchild">
   ...
</xsl:template>
```

Then when you import this stylesheet in another, you can override the templates matching `child`or `grandchild`as you wish.

Comment: Yes. People often have difficulty explaining just WHY people should use apply-templates instead of for-each, and overridability is one of the most tangible benefits.

Answer (score 2):

The tactic here would be to define a second template matching `parent` to ensure the imported one never runs (since you cannot change the imported one, nor suppress its behaviour once it matches).

By default, imported templates have LOWER priority than native ones, so simply defining another template should solve this.

You can also control priority by giving templates a `priority` attribute. The higher it is, the more likely it is to match a nodeset (meaning a lower priority one will not).

Template modes are also an option, but I think you have enough to be going on with here.

[XML Transforms - xsl:template (priority)](http://www.edankert.com/transforms/xslt.template-priority.html)

[XSLT  Element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_template.asp)

Comment: Beat me to it, by about 5 seconds.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to use everything else from the template so I cannot override whole template.

Comment: This is impossible. If you want some ports of the imported template to run but not others, you will have to duplicate the template as I described, but remove the bits you don't want.

Comment: This is a rather loose and inaccurate interpretation of the rules for import precedence. In particular: 1. An imported template has *always* lower import precedence than a template in the *importing* stylesheet. 2. There is no such term as "native template". 3. The `priority` attribute of `xsl;template` is only considered if two templates have the same import precedence (e.g. belong to the same stylesheet). See: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#dt-import-precedence

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: You don't have to withdraw your answer as this one contains rather loose and incorrect statements -- see my previous comment. I would encourage you to come up with a more precise/correct answer.

Comment: Utkanos, Also, please, do not quote non-authoritative sources as they as a rule misinterprete and reflect incorrectly the only authoritative source -- The XSLT W3C Specification:  http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116